# Sorting out ip address in R base on ip range

Tags: r, loops, sorting

I am currently stucked at sorting out a specific ip address to an ip range of A - B.

For example.

```
       Col A      Col B     Col C
1    10.0.0.0  10.0.0.255   1.5.2.1
2    10.0.1.0  10.0.3.255   60.5.1.30
3    10.0.4.0  10.0.4.255   10.0.0.233
.
.
.
605  60.5.1.0  60.5.1.255   10.0.2.254
.
.
```

so on and on for the X amount of rows in col A and B till it reaches the end of network address (Around 1mil rows~)

Col A and B is actually the ip starting range and ip ending range while my intention is to sort it out such that for example, Col C 10.0.0.233 should belong to row 1 instead of row 3.

Is there any way I can sort all the different ip addresses in col C such that it belongs to the row of col A and B?

Thanks :)

Edit: I am using data table if it may matter. Cheers.
Edit2: I need to make it such at row 2 col c will fit into row 605 while row 605 Col C will go into row 2, etc.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your data.table, but for future questions please use `dput()` per the R tag description to make reproducing your data easier. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @Hack-R what do you mean by repoducing data table?

Comment: Are there any overlaps in the IP ranges `[Col_A, Col_B]`? What should happen when there is no IP range `Col_C` fits in? Should that value be dropped?

Comment: Hi @UweBlock no,  there is not a single overlap in the IP range of col a and B. If there is no IP range that col C fits in col C should return NA.

Answer (score 1):

The following attempt uses a rolling right join, i.e. it tries to find for *all* values in `Col_C` a matching IP range `[Col_A, Col_B]`. No `Col_C` value is dropped but IP ranges without matching value in `Col_C` are dropped.

Package `iptools` is used to convert IP addresses from  human-readable representation to numeric representation.

```
library(data.table)
# Development version 1.9.7
ip <- fread( "id       Col_A      Col_B     Col_C
             1    10.0.0.0  10.0.0.255   1.5.2.1
             2    10.0.1.0  10.0.3.255   60.5.1.30
             3    10.0.4.0  10.0.4.255   10.0.0.233
             605  60.5.1.0  60.5.1.255   10.0.2.254
             ")

# convert strings to integers: an ip address actually is a 32 bit number
ip_cols <- paste0("Col_", LETTERS[1:3])
num_cols <- paste0("num_", LETTERS[1:3])
ip[, (num_cols) := lapply(.SD, iptools::ip_to_numeric), .SD = ip_cols]
# add column to join on (for clarity)
ip[, num_join := num_A]
# right join
result <- ip[ip[, .(Col_C, num_C)], on = .(num_join = num_C), roll = TRUE][order(id)]
# check upper bound - in case there are gaps in the IP ranges
result[num_join > num_B, c(ip_cols, num_cols) := NA][]

    id    Col_A      Col_B      Col_C      num_A      num_B      num_C   num_join    i.Col_C
1:   1 10.0.0.0 10.0.0.255    1.5.2.1  167772160  167772415   17105409  167772393 10.0.0.233
2:   2 10.0.1.0 10.0.3.255  60.5.1.30  167772416  167773183 1006960926  167772926 10.0.2.254
3: 605 60.5.1.0 60.5.1.255 10.0.2.254 1006960896 1006961151  167772926 1006960926  60.5.1.30
4:  NA       NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA   17105409    1.5.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the functionality that you are looking for, but the idea is matching ColA and ColC with those that match the numbers before the 3rd point (.).

If so I think this might do the trick

```
 df <- data.frame(ColA=c("10.0.0.0","10.0.1.0","10.0.4.0"),
             ColB=c("10.0.0.255","10.0.3.255","10.0.4.255"),
             ColC=c("1.5.2.1","60.5.1.30","10.0.0.233"))

require(dplyr)
DF1 <- df %>% select(1,2) %>% mutate(ColMatch=substr(start = 1,stop = as.numeric(regexpr(".([^.]*)$",df$ColA))-1,ColA))
DF2 <- df %>% select(3) %>% mutate(ColMatch=substr(start = 1,stop = as.numeric(regexpr(".([^.]*)$",df$ColC))-1,ColC)) 
DF <- left_join(DF1,DF2) %>% select(-ColMatch)
head(DF)

 ColA       ColB       ColC
1 10.0.0.0 10.0.0.255 10.0.0.233
2 10.0.1.0 10.0.3.255       <NA>
3 10.0.4.0 10.0.4.255       <NA>
```

Comment: Hi @Eduardo_Clark is it possible to limit down to such that it fits each of the ip range instead of the 4th octet? cheers

Comment: Ok so I don't know much about IP ranges, so you are telling me that ColA and ColB are an interval? And you want to asign a ColC that fits into that interval? If yes how does the range work, is 10.0.1.0 the next ip after 10.0.0.255?

Comment: Yes @Eduardo_Clark :)